# Kernel panic for com.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl

Tags: catalina, kernel-panic, kernel-extensions

Recently, every time I let my Macbook Pro on MacOS Catalina go to sleep, I get "Your computer was restarted because of a problem" when I log back in. Here is the report that gets sent to Apple automatically:

```
Machine-check capabilities: 0x0000000000000c0b
 family: 6 model: 142 stepping: 10 microcode: 202
 signature: 0x806ea
 Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8569U CPU @ 2.80GHz
 11 error-reporting banks
Processor 0: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
 IA32_MC4_STATUS(0x411): 0xba00000011000402
 IA32_MC4_MISC(0x413):   0x0000000000000000
Processor 1: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
 IA32_MC4_STATUS(0x411): 0xba00000011000402
 IA32_MC4_MISC(0x413):   0x0000000000000000
Processor 4: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
 IA32_MC4_STATUS(0x411): 0xba00000011000402
 IA32_MC4_MISC(0x413):   0x0000000000000000
Processor 5: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
 IA32_MC4_STATUS(0x411): 0xba00000011000402
 IA32_MC4_MISC(0x413):   0x0000000000000000
Processor 6: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
 IA32_MC4_STATUS(0x411): 0xba00000011000402
 IA32_MC4_MISC(0x413):   0x0000000000000000
Processor 7: IA32_MCG_STATUS: 0x0000000000000005
 IA32_MC4_STATUS(0x411): 0xba00000011000402
 IA32_MC4_MISC(0x413):   0x0000000000000000
mp_kdp_enter() timed-out on cpu 4, NMI-ing
mp_kdp_enter() NMI pending on cpus: 0 1 2 3 5 6 7
mp_kdp_enter() timed-out during locked wait after NMI;expected 8 acks but received 1 after 11218836 loops in 1404000000 ticks
panic(cpu 4 caller 0xffffff8007061b0c): "Machine Check at 0xffffff8007074de4, registers:\n" "CR0: 0x000000008001003b, CR2: 0x000000010d30c000, CR3: 0x0000000459507025, CR4: 0x00000000003626e0\n" "RAX: 0x00000ee9ca19c74a, RBX: 0x00000ee9ca19e68a, RCX: 0x000000005b2b0805, RDX: 0x0000000000000000\n" "RSP: 0xffffff92203735b0, RBP: 0xffffff92203735b0, RSI: 0x0000000000000040, RDI: 0x0000000000001f40\n" "R8:  0xffffff7f8aeac300, R9:  0xffffff81d4d6c450, R10: 0x0000000000000000, R11: 0x0000000000000000\n" "R12: 0xffffff803d8d1000, R13: 0xffffff803d8d3368, R14: 0x0000000000001f40, R15: 0x000000007fffffff\n" "RFL: 0x0000000000000206, RIP: 0xffffff8007074de4, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010\n" "Error code: 0x0000000000000000\n"@/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/xnu/xnu-6153.80.8.0.1/osfmk/i386/trap_native.c:168
Backtrace (CPU 4), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8006d53310 : 0xffffff8006f37beb 
0xffffff8006d53360 : 0xffffff800706f4b5 
0xffffff8006d533a0 : 0xffffff8007060f2e 
0xffffff8006d533f0 : 0xffffff8006edea40 
0xffffff8006d53410 : 0xffffff8006f372d7 
0xffffff8006d53510 : 0xffffff8006f376bb 
0xffffff8006d53560 : 0xffffff80076ce059 
0xffffff8006d535d0 : 0xffffff8007061b0c 
0xffffff8006d536c0 : 0xffffff80076ce1d8 
0xffffff8006d536d0 : 0xffffff8006edf29f 
0xffffff92203735b0 : 0xffffff8006f32b7c 
0xffffff92203735d0 : 0xffffff7f8adebafa 
0xffffff9220373610 : 0xffffff7f8ae07549 
0xffffff9220373640 : 0xffffff7f8ae2b75e 
0xffffff9220373690 : 0xffffff7f8ae2caf2 
0xffffff92203736b0 : 0xffffff800763adce 
0xffffff92203736f0 : 0xffffff7f8ae2cb8d 
0xffffff9220373740 : 0xffffff7f8ad99409 
0xffffff9220373760 : 0xffffff7f8ad99026 
0xffffff9220373820 : 0xffffff7f8ad99790 
0xffffff92203738a0 : 0xffffff7f8b31f003 
0xffffff9220373910 : 0xffffff800763adce 
0xffffff9220373950 : 0xffffff7f8b31f743 
0xffffff92203739a0 : 0xffffff7f8ad99026 
0xffffff9220373a60 : 0xffffff7f8ad99790 
0xffffff9220373ae0 : 0xffffff7f8ad96fef 
0xffffff9220373b60 : 0xffffff800766b9f3 
0xffffff9220373ca0 : 0xffffff800701ecf2 
0xffffff9220373db0 : 0xffffff8006f3da68 
0xffffff9220373e10 : 0xffffff8006f146f5 
0xffffff9220373e70 : 0xffffff8006f2b1a5 
0xffffff9220373f00 : 0xffffff8007047555 
0xffffff9220373fa0 : 0xffffff8006edf226 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl(4.5.21)[5F6E3B1A-89D8-3BBA-A0D6-47C8CC5BDAE6]@0xffffff7f8ad96000->0xffffff7f8ad9ffff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[7E431106-13F6-3B6A-8B16-24104ABFFAA5]@0xffffff7f87910000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(569.4)[D548D0A9-2FB2-3DC1-8CA6-8558369456FE]@0xffffff7f8ac82000
         com.apple.driver.AppleIntelCFLGraphicsFramebuffer(14.0.4)[1827BD86-0F19-34B6-8B58-0BDE4E57E0F1]@0xffffff7f8ada0000->0xffffff7f8afcdfff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[7E431106-13F6-3B6A-8B16-24104ABFFAA5]@0xffffff7f87910000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[6C3E59B8-E68D-3A98-AF3D-AFEDCEECCEA4]@0xffffff7f87907000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(438.2.8)[41E23715-3BC1-3FA1-93C4-F95753C14355]@0xffffff7f8acd3000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily(47)[D0707AF6-F6B6-34AB-81D3-F86AE16571CC]@0xffffff7f87849000
            dependency: com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl(4.5.21)[5F6E3B1A-89D8-3BBA-A0D6-47C8CC5BDAE6]@0xffffff7f8ad96000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(569.4)[D548D0A9-2FB2-3DC1-8CA6-8558369456FE]@0xffffff7f8ac82000
         com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy(4.5.21)[B2DD14DD-DF45-3B46-8A43-BF9F861A9D66]@0xffffff7f8b317000->0xffffff7f8b32afff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl(4.5.21)[7ABF5232-AFBE-36DA-B8D4-BD0C486AB3B5]@0xffffff7f8b314000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[6C3E59B8-E68D-3A98-AF3D-AFEDCEECCEA4]@0xffffff7f87907000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[7E431106-13F6-3B6A-8B16-24104ABFFAA5]@0xffffff7f87910000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(569.4)[D548D0A9-2FB2-3DC1-8CA6-8558369456FE]@0xffffff7f8ac82000
            dependency: com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl(4.5.21)[5F6E3B1A-89D8-3BBA-A0D6-47C8CC5BDAE6]@0xffffff7f8ad96000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: displaypolicyd
Boot args: chunklist-security-epoch=0 -chunklist-no-rev2-dev

Mac OS version:
19D49f

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 19.3.0: Sun Dec  8 22:27:29 PST 2019; root:xnu-6153.80.8.0.1~15/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 9EC18232-E356-30D5-84B8-282F31C3917B
Kernel slide:     0x0000000006c00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8006e00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8006d00000
System model name: MacBookPro15,2 (Mac-827FB448E656EC26)
System shutdown begun: NO

System uptime in nanoseconds: 16398850896048
last loaded kext at 681454488657: >usb.cdc.acm  5.0.0 (addr 0xffffff7f8b3b1000, size 32768)
loaded kexts:
com.getdropbox.dropbox.kext 1.10.3
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  6.1.2
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  6.1.2
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 6.1.2
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 6.1.2
com.google.santa-driver 0.9.33
>usb.!UHostBillboardDevice  1.0
>AudioAUUC  1.70
>!AGraphicsDevicePolicy 4.5.21
@fileutil   20.036.15
@AGDCPluginDisplayMetrics   4.5.21
>!AHV   1
|IOUserEthernet 1.0.1
|IO!BSerialManager  7.0.2f5
>!AUpstreamUserClient   3.6.8
>AGPM   111.4.2
>!APlatformEnabler  2.7.0d0
>X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
>pmtelemetry    1
>AGDCBacklightControl   4.5.21
>!A!IKBLGraphics    14.0.4
@Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X    7.0.0
>!ABacklight    180.1
>ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
>!AThunderboltIP    3.1.3
>BridgeAudioCommunication   6.55
>!AGFXHDA   100.1.423
>!AMCCSControl  1.13
>!ABridgeAudio!C    6.55
>!A!IPCHPMC 2.0.1
>!ATopCaseHIDEventDriver    3430.1
>!AHIDALSService    1
>!A!ICFLGraphicsFramebuffer 14.0.4
>!A!ISlowAdaptiveClocking   4.0.0
>!AAVEBridge    6.1
>!AFIVRDriver   4.1.0
@filesystems.autofs 3.0
@filesystems.apfs   1412.80.1
>BCMWLANFirmware4355.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4364.Hashstore  1
>BCMWLANFirmware4377.Hashstore  1
>!AFileSystemDriver 3.0.1
@filesystems.hfs.kext   522.0.9
@BootCache  40
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeDataless    1.0.0d1
@!AFSCompression.!AFSCompressionTypeZlib    1.0.0
>!AVirtIO   1.0
>!ABCMWLANBusInterfacePCIe  1
@private.KextAudit  1.0
>!ASmartBatteryManager  161.0.0
>!AACPIButtons  6.1
>!ASMBIOS   2.1
>!AACPIEC   6.1
>!AAPIC 1.7
$!AImage4   1
@nke.applicationfirewall    303
$TMSafetyNet    8
@!ASystemPolicy 2.0.0
|EndpointSecurity   1
>usb.cdc.acm    5.0.0
>usb.serial 6.0.0
>!UAudio    320.49
>!AGraphicsControl  4.5.21
|IOUSBUserClient    900.4.2
|IOAVB!F    800.17
>!ASSE  1.0
>!ABacklightExpert  1.1.0
>IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
>!AHDA!C    283.15
|IOHDA!F    283.15
@!AGPUWrangler  4.5.21
>!AHIDKeyboard  209
|IONDRVSupport  569.4
>!ASMBus!C  1.0.18d1
>X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
>!AThunderboltEDMSink   4.2.2
>!AThunderboltDPOutAdapter  6.2.4
>!AActuatorDriver   3430.1
>IOPlatformPlugin!F 6.0.0d8
>!AHS!BDriver   3430.1
>IO!BHIDDriver  7.0.2f5
>!AMultitouchDriver 3430.1
>!AInputDeviceSupport   3420.4
>!ASMBusPCI 1.0.14d1
|IO!BHost!CUARTTransport    7.0.2f5
|IO!BHost!CTransport    7.0.2f5
>!A!ILpssUARTv1 3.0.60
>!A!ILpssUARTCommon 3.0.60
>!AOnboardSerial    1.0
@!AGraphicsDeviceControl    4.5.21
|IOAccelerator!F2   438.2.8
|IOGraphics!F   569.4
|IOSlowAdaptiveClocking!F   1.0.0
@plugin.IOgPTPPlugin    810.1
|IOEthernetAVB!C    1.1.0
@kext.triggers  1.0
>!UMergeNub 900.4.2
>usb.IOUSBHostHIDDevice 1.2
>usb.cdc.ecm    5.0.0
>usb.cdc.ncm    5.0.0
>usb.cdc    5.0.0
>usb.networking 5.0.0
>usb.!UHostCompositeDevice  1.2
>usb.!UHub  1.2
>!AXsanScheme   3
>usb.!UVHCIBCE  1.2
>usb.!UVHCI 1.2
>usb.!UVHCICommonBCE    1.0
>usb.!UVHCICommon   1.0
>!AEffaceableNOR    1.0
|IOBufferCopy!C 1.1.0
|IOBufferCopyEngine!F   1
|IONVMe!F   2.1.0
>!AThunderboltPCIDownAdapter    2.5.2
>!AThunderboltDPInAdapter   6.2.4
>!AThunderboltDPAdapter!F   6.2.4
>!AHPM  3.4.4
>!A!ILpssI2C!C  3.0.60
>!A!ILpssDmac   3.0.60
|IOSurface  269.6
@filesystems.hfs.encodings.kext 1
|IOAudio!F  300.2
@vecLib.kext    1.2.0
>!AThunderboltNHI   5.8.4
|IOThunderbolt!F    7.4.8
>!ABCMWLANCore  1.0.0
>mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
>IOImageLoader  1.0.0
|IOSerial!F 11
|IO80211!FV2    1200.12.2b1
>corecapture    1.0.4
|IOSkywalk!F    1
>usb.!UHostPacketFilter 1.0
|IOUSB!F    900.4.2
>!A!ILpssI2C    3.0.60
>!A!ILpssGspi   3.0.60
>usb.!UXHCIPCI  1.2
>usb.!UXHCI 1.2
>!AEFINVRAM 2.1
>!AEFIRuntime   2.1
>!ASMCRTC   1.0
|IOSMBus!F  1.1
|IOHID!F    2.0.0
$quarantine 4
$sandbox    300.0
@kext.!AMatch   1.0.0d1
>!AKeyStore 2
>!UTDM  489.60.3
|IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice  422.0.2
>!ACredentialManager    1.0
>KernelRelayHost    1
>!ASEPManager   1.0.1
>IOSlaveProcessor   1
>!AFDEKeyStore  28.30
>!AEffaceable!S 1.0
>!AMobileFileIntegrity  1.0.5
@kext.CoreTrust 1
|CoreAnalytics!F    1
|IOTimeSync!F   810.1
|IONetworking!F 3.4
>DiskImages 493.0.0
|IO!B!F 7.0.2f5
|IO!BPacketLogger   7.0.2f5
|IOUSBMass!SDriver  157.40.7
|IOSCSIArchitectureModel!F  422.0.2
|IO!S!F 2.1
|IOUSBHost!F    1.2
>usb.!UCommon   1.0
>!UHostMergeProperties  1.2
>!ABusPower!C   1.0
|IOReport!F 47
>!AACPIPlatform 6.1
>!ASMC  3.1.9
>watchdog   1
|IOPCI!F    2.9
|IOACPI!F   1.4
@kec.pthread    1
@kec.corecrypto 1.0
@kec.Libm   1
```

Solutions I've read for similar situations is to uninstall the application with the offending kernel extension, but `com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl` seems like something that comes with the operating system? Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: have you used the Apple Diagnostics tool to check for hardware failure?